# How to hide ReplyKeyboardMarkup after user click in Telegram Bot API

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I am using Node.js [telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/mast/telegram-bot-api).

Idea:

1. Show a custom keyboard with one button - "Share my phone number".
2. When user clicks this button, contact should be sent and button should be removed from screen.

Here is a code I am using right now:

```js
bot.sendMessage({
    text: 'Please give us your phone number',
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        keyboard: [
            [{
                text: 'Share my phone number',
                request_contact: true
            }]
        ],
        resize_keyboard: true,
        one_time_keyboard: true
    })
});
```

Problems:

- When user clicks "Share my phone number" button, it shares his contact but button is visible even after that.
- When I am not using `request_contact` flag, `one_time_keyboard` works correctly (hides the button after its usage), but even in that case it just hides the button, so user can click an icon to bring it back to screen, which is not good at all.

Please tell me if I am doing something wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found it.

Here is a solution:

```js
bot.sendMessage({
    chat_id: message.chat.id,
    text: 'Some text...',
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        hide_keyboard: true
    })
});
```

Comment: hide_keyboard has been renamed to remove_keyboard since API 2.3.

Comment: Notice it seems not to work if you send and empty message or even only 1 space.

Answer (score 10):

`hide_keyboard` has been renamed to `remove_keyboard` since [API 2.3](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#november-21-2016).

```
bot.sendMessage({
    chat_id: message.chat.id,
    text: 'Some text...',
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        remove_keyboard: true
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`editMessageReplyMarkup`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) and update that message's `replyMarkup` with null string(`''`) after client user's click recieved.

**UPDATE** this is applicable for inline keyboards.

Comment: here is what I am getting now:

`{ ok: false, error_code: 400, description: 'Bad Request: Message can\'t be edited' }`

Comment: you should provide message id too. Last Message Id that you have sent and have contained the keyboard markup